# MongoDB: How to ensure read from a particular secondary from shard cluster?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

Here, I am having a mongo cluster setup with two config server, two shards each having 3 nodes and one mongos server. For e.g.

**Config servers**
IP1 configsvr1
IP2 configsvr2

**Shard 1**
IP3 shardsvr1 (Primary)
IP4 shardsvr2 (Secondary)
IP5 shardsvr3 (Secondary)

**Shard 2**
IP6 shardsvr4 (Primary)
IP7 shardsvr5 (Secondary)
IP8 shardsvr6 (Secondary)

IP9 mongos

Now, Is it possible to make all read operations on a particular node of each shard let's say -

All read operation should be perform in shard 1 over node 'shardsvr3' and in shard 2 over shardsvr6.

Please share your thoughts!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: i m not sure if you say read from a particular secondary or a member, because a secondary can be elected as a primary, but if you want that member to always be secondary mark it as priority 0 member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring, I came to know that it is possible to perform all read operations on a particular secondary node.

Here are the few steps to do that -

- Add tag to secondary node
  conf = rs.conf()
  conf.members[0].tags = {"use": "production"  }
  rs.reconfig(conf)
- set read preference secondary 
  db.getMongo().setReadPref('secondary')
- Now query by passing tag in query string

Useing spring-data-mongodb

MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder()
                .connectTimeout(connectionTimeoutInterval)
                .socketTimeout(socketTimeoutInterval)
                .serverSelectionTimeout(serverSelectionTimeoutInterval)
                .readPreference(TaggableReadPreference.secondary(new TagSet(createTagList())))
                .build();

return new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(host, port),
                                   Collections.singletonList(MongoCredential.createCredential(dbUserName, databaseName, dbPassword.toCharArray())),
                                   mongoClientOptions);